# Is there a built-in or package solution for managing references in text files?

Tags: text-editing, text

I'm currently writing up a design document and I want to include a number of references to external documents/URLs. I can manually add reference brackets and links so that:

```
See the external file blah.txt [1]
....
(at bottom of file)
References
==========
[1] http://example.com/blah.txt
```

However this is going to be prone to errors over the document as I add new references. Is there a built-in or 3rd party package to make adding and managing these references easier?

Comment: Why not use Markdown?  Your example is pretty close to it already.

Comment: @lunaryorn: the project I'm working on doesn't use Markdown for it's design documents. Having said that I could just edit the files in _markdown-mode_ I guess.

Comment: I see.  But still, you could probably just steal the code for references from Markdown Mode, and adapt it accordingly.

Comment: You can even use org-mode and export to ascii.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like Markdown or Org seems appropriate here, but if you are just looking for an easier way to manage footnotes you can enable `footnote-mode`. That provides key-bindings for adding a new footnote, jumping between the reference and the footnote, and so on.